# Flutter use Future return value in other file

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I have a problem I have in one file(Recipe.dart) a method called fetchAll() and I need this to return a list of my Recipes and to do this I created a Future:

```
 Future<List<Recipe>> recipes() async {
    // Get a reference to the database.
    final Database db = await database;

    // Query the table for all The Recipes.
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> title = await db.query('Rezepte');
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> ingredients = await db.query('Zutaten');
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> preperation =
        await db.query('Zubereitungen');
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> imgUrl = await db.query('Images');
    // Convert the List<Map<String, dynamic> into a List<Recipe>.
    return List.generate(title.length, (i) {
      return Recipe(
        id: i,
        name: title[i]['Rezept_Title'],
        ingredients: ingredients[i]['Zutat'],
        preperation: preperation[i]['Zubereitung'],
        imageURL: imgUrl[i]['Image_URl'],
      );
    });
  }
```

But this is in the Database helper file because otherwise I cant access the database so how can I connect these? So the function fetchAll() returns the list of Recipes which the future collects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a rough idea of how you might implement this.

I would start by creating a `RecipiesRepository`.

In there you could have a method that fetches the title, ingredients, preparation and images and returns them all in one easily readable object.

You could have a method that fetches everything in one request like so:

```
class RecipiesRepository {
  Future<RecipeModel> getRecipe(){
    return Future.wait([
      _getTitle(),
      _getIngredients(),
      _getPreparation(),
      _getImage(),
    ]).then((results) {
       // return an instance of a RecipeModel here from the results
    });
  }
}

// RecipeModel

class RecipeModel {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> title;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> ingredients;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> preparations;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> imageUrls;

  RecipeModel({
    this.title,
    this.ingredients,
    this.preparations,
    this.imageUrls,
  });
}
```

Then you can use the `FutureBuilder` widget.

```
// Create a new instance of RecipesRepository somewhere, giving you `_recipiesRepository`

FutureBuilder(
  future: _recipiesRepository.getRecipe(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // snapshot.data will be your RecipeModel
      return List.generate(snapshot.data.title.length, (i) {
        return Recipe(
          id: i,
          name: snapshot.data.title[i]['Rezept_Title'],
          ingredients: snapshot.data.ingredients[i]['Zutat'],
          preperation: snapshot.data.preparations[i]['Zubereitung'],
          imageURL: snapshot.data.imageUrls[i]['Image_URl'],
        );
      });
      
      
    else {
      // Show a spinner of something for a default view
    }
  }
)
```